# Two package.json Files With React & Firebase Functions

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I’m learning about React and plan to use Firebase and Firebase Functions in an app. When I create a React project I am given a package.json file.

If I add Firebase Functions to the project I am given a second package.json file in the functions folder.

Is this advisable or does it create a specific issue?

If two files is ok, where would you add future scripts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's completely fine to have multiple `package.json`s in a project so long as they aren't at the same level in the directory

your use case sounds like it's correct to use both but just remember to install future packages in the correct one. You should keep the firebase functions one inside `/firebase-functions` package and then only  install firebase function related stuff

in your other directory use this for installing `node_modules` you will use for your project. and remember you will need to install `firebase` in this `package.json` as you'll be using it in this project

again for future scripts, just add them to the relevant directory

Comment: Thank you! This is very helpful. This makes sense.